# error: Variable does not exist in soql

Tags: error

here is the query i am using:

```
bilan1 = [select id,valider__c,poste__c,Statut__c,Poste__r.Date_dernier_bilan__c, date_bilan__c, moyenne_du_bilan__c from Bilan_de_positionnement__c where poste__c in: collID and date_bilan__c =:Poste__r.Date_dernier_bilan__c  order by date_bilan__c asc];
```

i get this error:

```
Variable does not exist: Poste__r.Date_dernier_bilan__c
```

when i remove the condition `and date_bilan__c =:Poste__r.Date_dernier_bilan__`c the error disappears even though the `Poste__r.Date_dernier_bilan__c`field is fetched in the query meaning that the variable  `Poste__r.Date_dernier_bilan__c` does exist, am i messing something ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you don not need :  match fields. : for variables. so query should be like :

```
bilan1 = [select id,valider__c,poste__c,Statut__c,Poste__r.Date_dernier_bilan__c, date_bilan__c, moyenne_du_bilan__c from Bilan_de_positionnement__c where poste__c in: collID and date_bilan__c = Poste__r.Date_dernier_bilan__c  order by date_bilan__c asc];
```

it might help you.

Comment: I get another **error: expecting a colon, found 'Poste__r.Date_dernier_bilan__c'**, so i think the colon is required

Comment: You can't do it like that, you can use only apex variables for such comparison or create another sub-select but it won't work as it support only Id fields. So the only way is first get those dates in apex variable and then do a select.

Comment: @ Oles Malkov i will try that right away

Comment: @ Oles Malkov can't we write sub-query ??

Comment: at least the code get saved without errors this time, i will check if the results are as expected